# How to clear BackStack?

Tags: android, back-stack

in my application there are 4 activities, which are A, B, C, D

From activity "A", its a splash screen

```
Intent intent = null;
if(userLogin()) {
  intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
}
else {
  intent = new Intent(A.this, c.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
}
```

both "A" and "B" call same activity "D" and it is Login or Logout screen
From activity "D"

```
String calledActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("CALLED_ACTIVITY");

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    if(calledActivity.equal("C") && userLogin()) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(D.this, B.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
    }
    else if(calledActivity.equal("B") && !userLogin()) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(D.this, C.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
    }
    else 
      finish();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Before calling "D" if user not login, The stack is "C"

After Calling "D" if usr not login, The stack is "C" -> "D"

after press back from activity "D" if user login, The stack is "C" -> "B"

But originally i want to, The stack is "B"

Please help me to sort out this problem, Thank you

Comment: its really confusing dear

Comment: Please tell what was your confusion

Answer (score 2):

Start B with following flags:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

This will clear all the views before B and stack will only contain B.

Although FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is available from API 11.

Answer (score 2):

Start new Activity with this code. and all stacks will be cleared.

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Registration.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);